# How can a static site generator link dynamic properties?

Tags: web-development

Using a static site generator has the advantage of themes, blog and hosting (via Netlify). How can this be combined with a login form, show a user is logged in and dynamic pages (flask backend), while still keeping the same styling and being perceived as a single app?

Comment: "advantage of themes, blog and hosting" - _advantage_ over what? (A "dynamic" site can do just the same.)

Comment: Load speed using measures such as testmysite.withgoogle.com and VCS integration for blog posts. Just realized there are web templates without the need of generators.

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be combined with a login form, show a user is logged in and dynamic pages...

It depends on how "static" your static site is.

Your static site would need *static* client-side JavaScript in order to communicate with the *dynamic* backend and to ultimately display the *dynamic* content. But now your site is arguably *dynamic*, rather than strictly "static".

The only difference is that the dynamic content is not transmitted as part of the initially response from the server, but in subsequent requests once the page has loaded.

Comment: Valid point. What is a good reference to implement this functionality against?

Comment: It sounds like what MrWhite is describing is what's known as a "single-page application", where a front-end using a framework such as Anguler, React, Vue, etc is served statically which then communicates with a backend over REST for any dynamic elements.